# Regular expression to extract string

Tags: javascript, regex

I got the following string:

```
"url("http://localhost/image/user/temp/n9cec42c939ab461cac7852c267413b1b.jpg")"
```

How can I extract the file name using a javascript regular expression?

I tried [^/]+$ but it keeps the ") at the end.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite close to what you wrote is

```
/[^\/]+(?=\"\)$)/
```

for example

```
/[^\/]+(?=\"\)$)/.exec(s)
```

where `s` is your example string returns the correct filename.

(explanation: With regular expressions the form `(?=...)` means something that must be following the match but that should not be considered part of the match).

Answer (score 0):

split on backslash, pop to get the last result, and remove the `")`

```
'url("http://localhost/image/user/temp/n9cec42c939ab461cac7852c267413b1b.jpg")'.split('/').pop().replace('\")', '')
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8QMSe/1)

Or if RegExp is just your thing:

```
var url = 'url("http://localhost/image/user/temp/n9cec42c939ab461cac7852c267413b1b.jpg")'; 
url.match(/.+\/(.+)\"\)/)[1]; // file name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[^/]+"\)$
```

would work on your example. If that's not what you're after, please provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 0):

With a regexp you can use:

```
'url("http://localhost/image/user/temp/n9cec42c939ab461cac7852c267413b1b.jpg")'.match(/\/([\d\w]+\.[\w]+)/)[1]
```

assuming your filename consists from a-z + 0-9 and a three character extension